# Atualizar valor de item dentro de dictonary no python

Tags: python

**SCRIPT**

```
for row in result_psql:
    if row in lds_data:
        print(lds_data[row]['status'])
    else: 
        continue
```

**OUTPUT**

```
NO
```

**OBJETIVO**

Gostaria de atualizar o valor **NO** para **YES**

**ESTRUTURA DO DICT**

```
lds_data = {cod_cliente: {'status': 'NO', 'nome_cliente': 'NOME_TESTE'}}
```

Comment: Não seria `lds_data[row]['status'] = 'YES'`?

Comment: Deu certo amigo, eu estava tentando com .update(), muito obrigado!